# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

I scrawled down the data and had to save the dataframe as utf-16 (Unicode) since the Latin/Spanish words were shown weird in the form of utf-8. I used the following code to save the dataframe:

```
 df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-16", sep = "\t", index = False)
```

when I try to read the file to clean the data using the following code:

```
 blogdata = pd.read_csv('c:/Users/hyoungm?Downloads/blogdata.csv')
```

it shows the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-15ec18f92889> in <module>()
----> 1 blogdata = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/blogdata.csv')

...

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Please see my screenshot here:

[image]

I don't know either how to save the original data without losing those Laint/Spanish words within English sentences or how to read Unicode data file. Can anybody please help me with solving this issue?

Answer (score 19):

Was facing same, you can try

```
blogdata = pd.read_csv('c:/Users/hyoungm?Downloads/blogdata.csv',sep = "\t", encoding='latin')
```

Answer (score 18):

There is a Python library which may help when the encoding is unknown: [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/)

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    print(chardet.detect(file.read()))
```

detect finds the encoding, and
'rb' will read the file in as binary

Comment: It's no so useful programmatically, but if you just need one-off encoding detection and have Notepad++ installed, it well give you that info (note: I have found that 'UCS-2 LE BOM' can be read using `encoding='utf-16'`)

Comment: This worked fine in a test I did, although I got a 'confidence' of 0.73. Not to rely on, isn't it?  Then, this is quite an "abnormal" method  for just reading text files ... And consider that none of this was needed in Python 2.7, which had not problem at all with such unicode stuff!

Comment: wow, that was brilliant! it worked for me

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're trying to decode your utf-16 encoded file with the utf-8 codec.

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can specify the codec by passing the `encoding` argument to the `read_csv()` function.

Could you try the following code?

```py
blogdata = pd.read_csv('c:/Users/hyoungm?Downloads/blogdata.csv', encoding = 'utf-16')
```

Hope this helps. And let me know if something is unclear.

**EDIT:** I guess the right file path should be 'c:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/blogdata.csv' with a '/' between 'hyoungm' and 'Downloads', so adapt the script accordingly if I'm right.

Comment: Thank you! It reads. But another issue arises. The data is combined in the first column, which has to be divided into 11 columns since each column shows different variable (e.g., blogger, country, joined data, the number followers, posting, etc.). Could you please help me with formatting the data in a table?

I tried 
     df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-16", "r"); df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-16", "rb"); df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-16", sep = ","); and df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-16", sep = "\t", index = False)

Comment: I tried to read the file anyway but still shows the same error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte'.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your file with sharable data? It would be useful to identify the right format.

Comment: Please see this link: github.com/GemmyMoon/MultipleUrls.git for the csv file. This is saved as a csv file with utf-16. Would you mind trying with this file?

Thank you for your edits in the answer. That was my typo and should be the slash. I tried the corrected code, but the result was the same.

Comment: I downloaded the file and just read it by running this command :
`blogdata = pd.read_csv('/home/seraphin/urls.csv')`

In your question, you're mentioning having troubles with a file that you encoded by yourself. Is it this file that I got on the link you gave me in the previous comment?

**Note:**  The file only contains urls, which can only contain ASCII characters. So, no need for utf-16 encoding.

Comment: Oh my, my apology for the mistake. Please see this new address: https://github.com/GemmyMoon/blogdata. I uploaded the csv file that I have now. Please let me know if you cannot access to this one. Thank you!

Comment: This file does not work. Actually, I'm not sure it has been encoded with the script you mentioned in your question.  
Could you please start from the beginning and let me know the result of this script? 
 ```
import pandas as pd

data = <yourdata>

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv('blogdatatest.csv', encoding='utf-16',sep = "\t" )
blogdata = pd.read_csv('blogdatatest.csv', encoding='utf-16',sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Thank you for your trial. If you don't mind, would you check out the file that I just added (named blogdatatest_encoding_utf-16.csv) on the same website?

Comment: I would prefer if you could first test the script in my previous comment. I need to be sure to start from the same base as you do.

Comment: I just added the blogdatatest file following your codes above. Could you please check this file? Thank you.

Comment: What was the result when you ran the code I shared here over?

Answer (score 4):

Try `pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding_errors= 'replace')` This replaces every file that couldn't be read in a format readable by the encoder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the case for OP but for completeness this error can also be triggered by reading binary files without `b` mode. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

If you are trying to read serialized data such as the files saved by `pickle` or `torch`, you need `open("filename","rb")` instead of `open("filename")`

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue recently when trying to save keras model.
What I did to solve it was to double all `forward and backslash` in this manner `//` and `\\`.

This way I would avoid situations like this where `\u` is a special unicode character and will be interpreted differently by windows.

```
c:\desktop\uranuimmodel.keras'
```

So I will rather change the above to

```
c:\\desktop\\uranuimmodel.keras'
```

You can read more [here](https://sebhastian.com/syntaxerror-unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-truncated-escape/)

I hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: I'm voting to delete this because it is not the same issue as in the OP. The question in the OP is about decoding the content of the file `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte`, while this answer is for `SyntaxError: 'unicodeescape'`. Two completely different issues. The issue in this answer is already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/7758804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37400974/7758804). As such, this answer should be deleted, because it's not relevant.